# Is there a way to push a branch to a repo where there are changes that i need to keep?

Tags: git

Ok this is what happens. A buddy and i opened 2 diferrent branches from the base branch, to work separately in different features of this app, let's say, mailers and active storage. The mailer branch is pushed to the master and now we want to push the active storage one, but we're afraid that we might overrun the changes done by the mailer feature.
Is there any way to avoid this?
If no, what's the best way to handle this?

Comment: you will overrun the changes if you both have changed some common code. Before you push your code, you have to pull the updated master branch and if you both have changed some common code then it will show conflict.

Comment: You seem to be confusing repos and branches -- you push to a repo and you merge with a branch.  You say "mailer branch is pushed to master" which makes no sense, as "master" usually names a branch, not a repo.  You would usually push the mailer branch to the upstream repo (still the mailer branch) and/or merge the mailer branch to the master branch and then push the master branch to the upstream repo.